# Changing Opacity of Vector layer in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, vector-layer

While importing a Shp file in Earth Engine, I want to control or change opacity/transparency of the layer. I have gone through almost all read me files, I find nothing.

This doesn't work:

```
Map.addLayer (ind_shp, {opacity: 0.5}, 'map');
```

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#mapaddlayer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works like this:

```
var shown = true; // true or false, 1 or 0 
var opacity = 0.5; // number [0-1]
var nameLayer = 'map'; // string
var visParams = {color: 'red'}; // dictionary: 
Map.addLayer(ind_shp, visParams, nameLayer, shown, opacity);
```

> Note:  For Features and FeatureCollections, the only supported key is "color"

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set opacity;  use setOpacity:

```
Map.setCenter(34.54, 39.09, 6);

var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

var LSIB_LAYER = ui.Map.Layer(dataset, {color: 'red'},'LSIB',true);

LSIB_LAYER.setOpacity(0.6)

Map.layers().set(1, LSIB_LAYER);
```